# How to write a custom report name in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to change the default report name (report.html) inside my test suite but can't find a way.

What are the different way to specify the report name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `--report` command line option (see [User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#report-file).)

For example:

```
pybot --report myoutput.html mysuite.robot
```

will name your report `myoutput.html` instead of the default `output.html`

Comment: Thank you Laurent, as always! I was hoping to name it by the value of one of my test suite variable as i need the report to have a unique name for each test suite. Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: you want to launch pybot for each of your suite to get a report for each of them? That does not look very convenient. Anyway, this will have to be shell scripting I guess (bash, batch etc.) where you can use a single variable for report and suite names.